# My jquery datatable ajax call does not reach server instead JSON format invalid alert is shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatable

I have a simple web page which contains a table. I need to fill the table using ajax call to server side method. I have used jquery DataTable. the code for jquery is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tableUserList").DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "dataSource": "",
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "AdminHome.aspx/getUsersForTable"
  });
});
```

My HTML table is

```
<table id="tableUserList" class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>UserID</th>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>UserType</th>
      <th>FirstName</th>
      <th>LastName</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

and my server side code is

```
[WebMethod]
public static string getUsersForTable()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConn"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Login.id,Login.username,Login.user_type,UserInfo.first_name,UserInfo.last_name,UserInfo.address,UserInfo.email,UserInfo.phone_no from Login,UserInfo where Login.id=UserInfo.id", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    using (con)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        con.Open();
        sda.Fill(ds);
    }
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    string data = serializer.Serialize(ds);
    return data;
}
```

The control does not reach server instead a alert message is displayed with message : DataTables warning: table id=tableUserList - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1.

I checked the url given in the message but did not find any solution.
What is it that I am doing wrong.

Comment: where is your ajax call in script,only datatable is there

Comment: Debug return of the data, it may not be valid JSON,

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have loaded the CDN or required plugins properly and also getUsersForTable returns the data,below is the code.

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'AdminHome.aspx/getUsersForTable',
                method: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#tableUserList').dataTable({
                        paging: true,
                        sort: true,
                        searching: true,
                        scrollY: 200,
                        data: data,
                            columns: [
                                { 'data': 'UserID' },
                                //rest follows with column names].
                //end of datatable
                });
               //end of success function
              }
               //end of ajax call
                });
              //end of ready event.
        });
```

Comment: still the same message is shown. This solution did not work for me. Sorry.